# Angular, mouseover speed is choppy?

Tags: javascript, css, angular, typescript

I'm trying to create a "tooltip" that follows the mouse around and disappears when it leaves it's location.  However, the tooltip created is slow, it doesn't follow my mouse around smoothly and seems choppy.  How do I fix this?

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-851aej?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

**TS:**

```
export class AppComponent {
  name = 'Angular';

  constructor(private el: ElementRef) {}

  first(e: { pageX: any; pageY: any }) {
    console.log(e.pageX, e.pageY);

    this.el.nativeElement.querySelector('#first').style.left =
      e.pageX.toString() + 'px';
    this.el.nativeElement.querySelector('#first').style.top =
      e.pageY.toString() + 'px';
    this.el.nativeElement.querySelector('#first').classList.add('show');
  }

  second(e: { pageX: any; pageY: any }) {
    this.el.nativeElement.querySelector('#first').style.left = '0px';
    this.el.nativeElement.querySelector('#first').style.top = '0px';

    this.el.nativeElement.querySelector('#first').classList.remove('show');
  }
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div (mouseover)="first($event)" (mouseleave)="second($event)"class="place-welcome">
<h2>This is a Panel</h2>
<p>Hello my darling</p>
</div>

<div id="first">asdasdasdasd</div>
```

Comment: Your StackBlitz link is no longer in line with your question. Probably better to fork your StackBlitz.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using [`mouseover`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mouseover_event) and [`mouseleave`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mouseleave_event), use:

- **[`mousenter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mouseenter_event)** to detect when the mouse enters the `div`. This is where you display the tooltip.
- **[`mousemove`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mousemove_event)** to detect when the mouse is moved inside the `div`. This is where you position the tooltip.
- **[`mouseleave`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mouseleave_event)** to detect when the mouse leaves the `div`. This is where you hide the tooltip.

In addition:

- Don't perform the same element query multiple times in one function, but perform the lookup once and store it in a variable. Possibly, you can even perform the lookup just once on component initialization, but that depends on the further logic of your component.
- Make sure to set `pointer-events` to `none` for the tooltip; if not, you will get interference from the mouse entering and leaving the tooltip.

---

Putting all of this together, you get the following code:

**Component:**

```
import { Component, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  name = 'Angular';

  constructor(private el: ElementRef) {}

  get tooltip() {
    return this.el.nativeElement.querySelector('#first');
  }

  enter() {
    this.tooltip.classList.add('show');
  }

  move(e: { pageX: number; pageY: number }) {
    const tooltipStyle = this.tooltip.style;
    tooltipStyle.left = e.pageX + 'px';
    tooltipStyle.top = e.pageY + 'px';
  }

  leave() {
    this.tooltip.classList.remove('show');
  }
}
```

**Template:**

```
<div
  (mouseenter)="enter()"
  (mousemove)="move($event)"
  (mouseleave)="leave()"
  class="place-welcome"
>
  <h2>This is a Panel</h2>
  <p>Hello my darling</p>
</div>

<div id="first">asdasdasdasd</div>
```

**Stylesheet:**

```
#first {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.place-welcome {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  background: red;
}

.show {
  opacity: 1 !important;
}
```

---

View on [StackBlitz](https://angular-htzhch.stackblitz.io)

Comment: Thank you!  Everything makes sense when I finally see it...the css pointer-event, first time seeing that, super helpful

Comment: I feel that you can use a template reference variable in div `<div #first id="first">` and pass to the function enter and move: `<div (mouseenter)="enter(first)" (mousemove)="move($event,first)"..>`. NOTE: the argument is yet the htmlElement

Comment: @Eliseo Probably, yeah. Or use a `@ViewChild`, but didn't want to introduce too many changes as I assume that this is just an MRE, and I don't know what the surrounding code looks like, how the element is created, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Mouseover can be an event that trigger many times in a few seconds, for example the cursor moves 1px while still being over the same htmlElement.

Considering that...

- try to avoid calling console.log always (include a condition of some kind)
- instead of calling this method every time  `this.el.nativeElement.querySelector('#first')` assign it to a variable en reuse it

```js
let first = this.el.nativeElement.querySelector('#first') ;
first.left = e.pageX.toString() + 'px';
first.style.top = e.pageY.toString() + 'px';
first.classList.add('show');
```

not only it makes your code more readable, it avoids query over and over to get the same result on each call to onmouseover

Comment: Thanks, good tips, had a bunch of code I need to refactor, been trying to make my code more readable